# dynotopo sculpting - which make the file to big

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

When I go into Dynotopo, I come with an 86 Mb file, and set it to constant detail 20, - and do a Little with the snakebrush, a Little inflation, and smooth - and then boom, after only 5-10 minutes i have 390 Mb file, and going rather slowly.

My computer is 16 gb ram and using a Nivida Geforce gtx 1660 graphic card. That I imagine is OK, on a not a specially small computer.

Can anybody tell me what to do?

I of course use the decimate modifier, but setting it to 0.3 only gets the mesh size down to 300 mb. it seems crazy that the mesh grows that fast.

[sculpture in 3 elements [image: ][1]]

Comment: Can't see the statistics in the status bar, so how many vertices/faces/edges has your object? How many the whole scene? Have you duplicated a sculpted object?

Comment: Does the model have several UV maps or weight groups?

Comment: its about 3millionverts and faces (cant remeber exact ) and it says 1,5 gb memory. It ends up being 370 mb fil. There is no weigth paint or uv mapping. its mostly a sculpture done with converted curve object to mesh, and skin modelling lines converted to medh